# Сравнение объектов по значению полей, если одним полем является List

Tags: c#

Есть 2 объекта, одним полем которого может являться List.

```
public class pDataStruct<T, O>
{
    public String Name;
    public T Tag;
    public O Object;
}
```

Например полем Object такого объекта может являться List или просто bool. Как грамотно перегрузить Equals или сравнивать объекты по значению полей Tag и Object. Можно ли реализовать универсальную функцию сравнения, которая вызывала нужный Equals для сравнения полей по значению.

Comment: Ничего лучше проверки на is IList/IEnumerable/ICollection в голову не приходит.

Comment: Универсальную функцию можно сделать, только пусть как пкркметр она принимает `IComparer<pDataStruct<T, O>>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать ключевые слова, даже изменяя регистр какого-то символа - является дурным тоном. (в вашем случае поле `public O Object;`);
2. Ситуации, когда у вас в одном случае поле может быть bool, а в другом List - является плохой реализацией вашей архитектуры, стоит подумать, как это сделать по другому для вашей задачи;
3. Нужно четко понимать какими будут `T` и `O` - что из этого может быть только типом значения, а что ссылочным типом, и для всех полей, что являются ссылочным типом стоит использовать метод `.Equals()`

Как пример:

```
object fst = 5, snd = 5;
bool eq1 = (fst == snd); // false

bool eq2 = fst.Equals(snd); // true
```

Но для списков лучше использовать метод `.SequenceEqual()`

В вашем случае, как вариант, можно воспользоваться сравнением типа и проверить, является ли он bool `if (Object is bool)` аналогично и для List